# Navigation Bar in Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently started using Bootstrap 3.0

I like especially the opportunity to create beautiful navigation bars, but I would give to be customized.

I would like to remove the **triangles**, and so far it is not difficult.
Once done, however, through the display: none property, I can not bring up the submenu.

In addition I would like the submenu not remain open forever, but only in situations of hover.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Here is a sample navigation bar: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HD22K/)

I hope someone can help me, **thanks in advance** to all

Comment: I don't see the issue for the caret at least: http://jsfiddle.net/HD22K/1/ or really for the hover: http://jsfiddle.net/HD22K/2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if you look at the big screen, you'll see that it does not work;)

Comment: I thank you, the second link seems to work

But when I see in mobile mode, the 'effect is not more than the desired one.
Just use media queries?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be modernizr or something similar to say `html.no-touch .dropdown:hover > ul { display: block; }`. That of course, assumes you're using modernizr.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the triangles in dropdown menu. You need not use display:none css rather remove the line: `<b class="caret"></b>`

Final Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HD22K/3/)